# How to access config vars from within another class in UserFrosting?

Tags: php, namespaces, userfrosting

can anyone give me a quick hand with namespaces and the UserFrosting environment?

To explain my issue, I'm using TCPDF to create a PDF document from data within UserFrosting. I've created a custom class, MyPDF, in the UserFrosting namespace so I can create a PDF within the UF namespace by typing `$pdf = new MyPDF(blahblah);` and that works fine.

The issue is with the MyPDF class itself - I need to be able to reference config vars from UF and don't know how I can do that - i.e.:

```
namespace UserFrosting;

 class MyPDF extends \TCPDF_TCPDF {

   public function Header() {
      $image_location = $this->_app->config('upload.path')
```

How can I access `config` from within `MyPDF`? :?:

I've tried:

```
class MyPDF extends \TCPDF_TCPDF {

 public function Header() {
    $ufapp = new UFModel();
    $image_location = $ufapp->config('upload.path')
```

... but no dice. I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot instantiate abstract class UserFrosting\UFModel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$app` is just the global instance of `UserFrosting` that the entire application runs on.  Since `UserFrosting` extends `Slim\Slim`, you can access it statically using the [`getInstance()` method](http://docs.slimframework.com/configuration/names-and-scopes/#fetch-by-name):

`$app = UserFrosting::getInstance();`

A better way, though, would be to actually pass `$app` into your `MyPDF` constructor.  However, depending on your situation and where else you are using `MyPDF`, that might be more difficult.

Comment: Thanks @alexw - I knew you'd have a simple solution somehow! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's written in error: **you can't instantiate a abstract class**. Create class which extends from `UFModel` and implement all abstract methods from this class.

For example, if your `UFModel` class looks like this:

```
<?php

abstract class UFModel
{
   abstract public function getValue();
}
```

you should create class which extends this class and implements all abstract methods:

```
<?php

class MyModel extends UFModel
{
   public function getValue()
   {
       return 'exampleValue';
   }
}
```

Now you can create object using `new` operator:

```
<?php

//...
$ufapp = new MyModel();
//...
```

[More about abstract classes in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)

Comment: But MyPDF class needs to extend TCPDF_TCPDF.  MyPDF is being instantiated within a class that extends UserFrosting\BaseController class - `$pdf = new MyPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);`  Hm..  I'm confused as hell by all this, sorry if the question isn't clear.. :(

Comment: But error is about instantiate `UFModel`, not `MyPDF` class.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that - I was just trying to find a solution and groping in the dark with that line.  The issue is that I need to access $app, which is the instance of the class I'm calling `new MyPDF()` from.  Without that, I can't access the `config[]` vars within the MyPDF class.

Comment: Actually, I could modify the parameters taken by the MyPDF constructor to take `$app` as an argument?